# Lowest members in column with enum column?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So my (MySQL) Looks like so:

> 'Table' -> Column : p_id, name, rank, branch(enum (Air Force, Army, Marines, Navy, None)), billet, etc etc

So I am trying to grab the branch with the lowest amount of members and trying to avoid getting anything from (None or Navy 'at this time') The main branches I want to grab stuff from would be Air Force, Army, and Marines. Showing the lowest amount of personnel / members from that branch

So this is what I have done

```
$stats['lowest'] = DB::run('SELECT MIN(branch) as min_branch FROM personnel')->fetchColumn();
```

```
Recruits should go to : <?php echo $stats['lowest']; ?>
```

It shows Air Force even though it has 3 members in it while Army and Marines haves 0 with the 'branch' title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for a group and count as a sub query

```
SELECT
    `a`.`branch`
FROM(
    SELECT 
        `personnel`.`branch`,
        COUNT(*) AS `c`    
    FROM 
        `personnel`
    WHERE 
        `personnel`.`branch` IN('Air Force','Army','Marines')
    GROUP BY 
        `personnel`.`branch`
    ORDER BY 
        `c` ASC
) AS `a`
LIMIT 1
```

BUT

Since you are trying to get `Army` and `Marines` which don't have any records... they wont be included in your query. So any result that is returned will never give you a 0 value.

It appears you are trying to count records that dont exist... which wont work without setting up a database view (although someone else might have a better answer)